# Как сохранить положение switch при выходе из программы под Android?

Tags: java, android, android-shared-preferences

Как сохранить  положение `switch` при выходе из программы?

Нужно, чтобы при выходе сохранялось положение, а при возврате в программу возвращалось на место.

Правка

```
package dima113xxx.coin_calculator;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate;
import android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat;

import android.widget.CompoundButton;

import static android.content.res.Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES;


public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {


    public SwitchCompat myswitch;



    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        myswitch=(SwitchCompat)findViewById(R.id.switch1);
        // пишем нужное в SharedPreferences
        SharedPreferences.Editor ed = getSharedPreferences("test", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        //ed.putInt("myVariable", ???);
        ed.commit();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("test", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        int myVariable = prefs.getInt("myVariable", 1);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        int currentNightMode = getResources().getConfiguration().uiMode & Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK;


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);




        myswitch=(SwitchCompat)findViewById(R.id.switch1);
        if (currentNightMode ==UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES) {
            myswitch.setChecked(true);
        }
        myswitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked){
                    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
                    recreate();

                }
                else {
                    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
                    recreate();
                }
            }


        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Вы хотите сохранять/восстанавливать состояние `checked` вашего `switch`?

Comment: ...........................Да

Comment: Обновил ответ .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При паузе пишите значение в `SharedPreferences`:

```
 protected void onPause() {
     super.onPause();

     // пишем нужное в SharedPreferences
     SharedPreferences.Editor ed = getSharedPreferences("test", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
     ed.putBoolean("switchState", myswitch.isChecked());
     ed.commit();
 }
```

А в `onCreate` получайте:

```
public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("test", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    boolean switchState = prefs.getBoolean("switchState", true);

    myswitch.setChecked(switchState);
}
```

Comment: getSharedPreferences(что тут писать?);

Comment: @Yacow там [поменяли что-то в последних версиях](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences). Как-то так теперь надо `getSharedPreferences("test", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)`

Comment: switchValue нужно заменить на мой  public SwitchCompat myswitch;?

Comment: @Yacow а можете код привести? А то я не совсем понимаю, про какой `switch` вы говорите )

Comment: Все работает СПАСИБО "Like"

Comment: @Yacow рад помочь (:

Comment: все таки нужна помощь 
куда можно показать код?

Comment: @Yacow вы можете отредактировать вопрос и прям туда вставить.

Comment: Все супер ,класс. Спасибо :)

Answer (score 3):

На мой взгляд самый нормальный вариант - `SharedPreferences`. Сохраняете в памяти любое нужное вам число, а при старте приложения вытаскиваете его из памяти.

```
SharedPreferences mSettings;

mSettings = getSharedPreferences(APP_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor editor = mSettings.edit();
editor.putInt(APP_PREFERENCES_NAME, value);
editor.apply();
```

[Вот](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/sharedpreferences.php) есть источник где все красиво расписано.